# Default Login not successful in spring boot 2.1.7

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have added `spring-security-starter` in pom.xml.After,than I got a login screen where I added the

```
Username =user
password= Autogenerated password by spring security
```

Hence the login was successful. But,when I added these properties in application.properties file:

```
spring.security.user.name=ashwin  
spring.security.user.password=ashwin
```

Then when I run the project,when i try to login using these username=ashwin and password=ashwin it is denying me and showing me **Bad credintals**.

My console printed is:

```
2019-08-17 10:16:02.470  INFO 16036 --- [           main] c.a.s.s.SpringSecurityDemoApplication    : Starting SpringSecurityDemoApplication on Ashwin with PID 16036 (E:\sp-brains\spring-security-demo\target\classes started by AshwinPC in E:\sp-brains\spring-security-demo)
2019-08-17 10:16:02.492  INFO 16036 --- [           main] c.a.s.s.SpringSecurityDemoApplication    : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2019-08-17 10:16:15.394  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2019-08-17 10:16:15.600  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2019-08-17 10:16:15.601  INFO 16036 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.22]
2019-08-17 10:16:16.524  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2019-08-17 10:16:16.524  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 13042 ms
2019-08-17 10:16:18.007  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-08-17 10:16:20.530  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5e39850, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@74fe5966, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@6c37bd27, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6b587673, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@49aa766b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@27fde870, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@1542af63, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@1603dc2f, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@4e4c3a38, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@677b8e13, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58cec85b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@398474a2, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@30331109, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4d0b0fd4, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2bcec6a6]
2019-08-17 10:16:21.438  INFO 16036 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-08-17 10:16:21.480  INFO 16036 --- [           main] c.a.s.s.SpringSecurityDemoApplication    : Started SpringSecurityDemoApplication in 20.703 seconds (JVM running for 22.771)
```

My main class :

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringSecurityDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringSecurityDemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

A testing controller to go after login:

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class HelloController {


    @GetMapping(value = "/")
    public String hello(){
        return "<h1>Hello World</h1>";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `inMemoryAuthentication` using `configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)` or `@Bean` of `UserDetailsService`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
          auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("ashwin").password("{noop}ashwin").roles("ADMIN");
    }

    //OR 

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        InMemoryUserDetailsManager manager = new InMemoryUserDetailsManager();
        manager.createUser(User.withUsername("ashwin").password("{noop}ashwin").roles("USER").build());
        return manager;
    }

}
```

Note: 
You can also simply prefix `{noop}` to your passwords in order for the `DelegatingPasswordEncoder` use the `NoOpPasswordEncoder` to validate these passwords. Notice that `NoOpPasswordEncoder` is deprecated though, as it is not a good practice to store passwords in plain text.

Comment: Doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/jc.html#hello-web-security-java-configuration